# Unable to load class 'com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExecutor'

Tags: android

I just got this new project off github and am trying to compile it in android studio for the first time, and am greeted with this error `Unable to load class 'com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExecutor`'. it also goes ahead to display some other solutions which i have tried out but still failed. Here is the full error display message

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExecutor'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
```

Comment: Here is a link to the project https://github.com/mlabouardy/daily-quotes

Comment: Can't find any bugtracker in the github repo

Comment: Opened an issue but it seems project is abandoned, but i want to work on it anyway.

Comment: Yes i did @Jonas

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Still did not work but thanks for all the help.